# How to create static table cells in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I see that [everybody](http://cdn4.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/StaticCells1.png) has these "Content" and "Section" option on Table View attributes tab. I don't see it in my Xcode. Where can I find it? I searched on the internet and there seems no one has the same problem as me.

I have used the UITableViewController, and I have selected the Table View, which the "Content" and "Section" option is supposed to be in the attributes tab.

[image]

Comment: You cannot create static cells in a nib file, only in a storyboard scene

Comment: @Paulw11 oh alright, thank you very much for the answer. I don't know why it's so hard to find out why it happens.